# How to correctly forward declare struct with "using XXX"?

Tags: c++, include, typedef, using, forward-declaration

There is a header file "api.h" that I have to use, and I can **NOT** modify it, but all names of  the structs in it are too long and with less readability, also the naming style of them is not similar to my project.

e.g. in file "api.h":

```
#pragma once
struct AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT1 {
   ...
};
struct AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT2 {
   ...
};
...
```

So, I created another header "common.h", so as to re-name them.

File "common.hpp":

```
#pragma once
#include "api.h"
namespace MyProject {
using ContraDef_t = AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT1;
using AccountDef_t = AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT2;
};
```

But I want to include it merely in implemental file( *.cpp ), instead of other header files, because I want to speed up the compiling process.
Suppose I declare a class in "myclass.hpp", and implement it in "myclass.cpp".
I try to add a forward declaration of struct ContraDef_t into "myclass.hpp", as following:

```
#pragma once
namespace MyProject {
struct ContraDef_t;
class MyClass_t {
   MyClass_t( const ContraDef_t * );
   ...
};
};
```

Then in "myclass.cpp":

```
#include "common.hpp"
#include "myclass.hpp"
namespace MyProject {
MyClass_t::MyClass_t( const ContraDef_t * pcd ) {
   ...
};
};
```

Finally, I can **NOT** pass the compiling with "error: using typedef-name ‘using ContraDef_t = struct AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT1’ after ‘struct’..."

How should I do? Any help or hints will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put only the forward declarations in the header and include that header:

```
// common.h
// dont include api.h here !
struct AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT1;
using ContraDef_t = AVERYVERYLONGLONGNAMEOFSTRUCT1;

// my_class.h
#include "common.h"
struct my_class{ 
    ContraDef_t* c;
};

// my_class.cpp
#include "my_class.h"
#include "api.h"
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I don't want to include "common.hpp" in "myclass.hpp", because I want to let "myclass.hpp" as simple as possible. any methods else ?

Comment: @Leon common.h only has forward declarations and the `using`, you cannot get it "simpler" than that

Comment: @Leon your `common.h` had `#include "api.h"` and I understood it is that include of `api.h` that you dont want to have in `my_class.h`. I dont do that